# Creating a NSIS Page that contains a Bitmap covering the whole window

Tags: installation, nsis

**Whats the best way to create a NSIS Welcome Page that has a Bitmap image that covers the whole dialog(main HWND) window?**

Is the best way to:

- Use MUI2 and specify the constants MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP and
  MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP_NOSTRETCH? I've tried this and the image
  sits over the top of the next/prev buttons and the welcome text. Is
  there a function call I can use to change the image windows' z-index?
- Create my own custom window? I know how to do that and how to create checkbox, button & etc. windows but not how to create an image window(I guess I create a static or label window then set the bitmap for that?)
- Maybe the plugin SkinnedControls has a way to do it? I have experimented with applying skins to buttons but haven't found anything that can create a welcome screen with a large bitmap in SkinnedControls. Plus the installer keeps crashing on clicking next(something to do with the Unicode version I think?).
- Maybe another way I dont know of?

Can you suggest the best way to create a welcome page that contains a bitmap that covers the whole dialog?

Comment: Did you read [NSIS nsDialogs Plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) - especially section [NSD_Create*](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html#mref-create)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very similar to this one: [Alter the z-index of windows on a NSIS MUI2 Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645433/alter-the-z-index-of-windows-on-a-nsis-mui2-page) so please read it at first.

As I said: it is very tricky to create whole background (it requires a lot of coding) but I can recommend you this solution:  [Graphical Installer for NSIS](http://graphical-installer.com/) for creating cool looking installer.