# Alter the z-index of windows on a NSIS MUI2 Page

Tags: installation, nsis, modern-ui

**Is it possible to set the z-index of the header bitmap window on a NSIS MUI2 Page?**

I am trying to make a window that contains a large bitmap sit behind the other windows(labels, checkboxes etc.) on the MUI2 Pages MUI_PAGE_WELCOME & MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS.

*I have seen I could use SetWindowPos but how do I access/find the HWND associated with the header bitmap?*

Also is there a way to set a static, label and checkboxes background to transparent? Maybe theres a Win32 flag I can use, or should I use a transparent bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are possible.

For accessing bitmap defined as MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP use it's ID which is 1046
(To see these IDs open appropriate .exe file in NSIS\Contrib\UIs\ folder with ResHacker)

Then use **GetDlgItem** OutputVar $HWNDPARENT 1046 to get handle on it.
In NSIS all WinAPI functions work well.

1) Creating whole background is very tricky - it requires a lot of coding.
Installer's window consists from outer and inner dialogs so you need to add two bitmaps (one for each dialog)
As this is a lot of code I can recommend you this solution: [Graphical Installer for NSIS](http://graphical-installer.com/) for creating cool looking installer.

2): Use **SetCtlColors** ControlHwnd TextColor transparent 
This works for most controls but there are some troubles with it on WinXP.
The other way is to subclass every control and override it's WM_PAINT message (writing simple C plug-in).